# Use Array in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

My question got down voted and put on hold because it is not specific enough. Ill try to specify

Before linq I would do this query

```
sql="SELECT products.* FROM products INNER JOIN productaccess ON products.id=productaccess.productid"
```

Now with the entity framework and link I can do this

```
var products = (from lProducts in db.Products 
            join lProductAccess in db.ProductAccess on lProducts.ID equals lProductAccess.ProductID  
            select lProducts).ToList();
```

But what if I want the flexibilty to get all products or only get the accessible objects

In sql I can do this

```
sql="SELECT products.* FROM products "
if (useProductAccess) {
    sql+=" INNER JOIN productaccess ON products.id=productaccess.productid"             
}
```

In Linq I have to make a separate linq statement.

```
if (useProductAccess) {
    var productsFiltered = (from lProducts in db.Products 
            join lProductAccess in db.ProductAccess on lProducts.ID equals lProductAccess.ProductID  
            select lProducts).ToList();
} else {
    var productsAll = (from lProducts in db.Products select lProducts).ToList();
}
```

Now, I could just get all the lProducts and then filter it in an additional linq statement with lProductAccess but then I am using an unnecessary large amount of data.

Is it an option to use:

```
var productsAccecible = (from lProductAccess in db.ProductAccess where lProductAccess.CustID==custID select lProductAccess).toArray();

var products = (from lProducts in db.Products 
                where (useProductAccess ?
                   productsAccessible.Contains(lProducts.ID) 
                   : true) 
            select lProducts).ToList();
```

Comment: Try the code and find out.  If you have a problem, then describe the problem here and we can help you address it.

Comment: why `1==1` when `true` achieves the same thing and is much more readable?

Comment: I know it works but I wanted to know if it is a workable solution. I've have  predicates and group joins but they make the linq statement complex and inflexible.

Comment: Edited original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the express profiler to see how the linq statement is translated into sql. It shows that the

```
productsAccessible.Contains(lProducts.ID)
```

part gets translated as

```
products.id in (comma seperated list of values)
```

My conclusion is it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Linq provider will not know how to transform the ternary operator (`?` and `:`) in a valid sql, you could try this:

```
var query = db.Products;

if (useProductAccess)
   query = query.Where(p => productsAccessible.Contains(p.ID));

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: The conditional operator can most certainly be translated into SQL, and the code you've provided doesn't even compile (you're assigning an `IQueryable` to `query` which isn't an `IQueryable`).

Comment: This seems like a nice solution but I am afraid if I split it up this way the query on the db will have to get executed multiple times for every where clause I add ?

Comment: @JohnHardCash It's pretty trivial to run the code and see for yourself if that actually happens.

Comment: @JohnHardCash the query will be executed when the code pass to `ToList()`.

Comment: @Servy, I use NHibernate here and and when I try to use the ternary operator, it throwns exceptions!

Comment: @FelipeOriani And if you used EF, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there possible drawbacks

Sure - it may produce an inefficient query, or it *may not even work*.

One thing to note is that your conditional operator won't compile; you can't return a `bool` and an `int` from the ternary operator.

Maybe you mean:

```
var products = (from lProducts in db.Products 
                where (useProductAccess ?
                       productsAccessible.Contains(lProducts.ID) 
                       : true) 
                select lProducts).ToList();
```

or build your query up using method syntax and only add the `where` clause if necessary.